# Doing one more iteration after DO-While loops stops?

Tags: java

I am writing a Babylonian algorithm for computing the square root of a positive number, and the iteration should keep going until the guess is within 1% of the previous guess.
the code that I have written gets the iteration going to the one before error is 1%. how can I make it to do one more iteration ? 
to get the question straight, is there a way to tell it iterate untill the error is <1% ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sqrt {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nplease enter the desired positive number in order to find its root of two: ");

        double num = kb.nextDouble();
        double guess=0; 
        double r, g1, error;    
        if (num>=0){
            guess = num/2;
            do{
                r = num/guess;
                g1 = guess;
                guess = (guess+r)/2;
                error = (guess-g1)/guess;
                if (error<0){
                    error = -error;
                }
            }

            while(error>0.01);
            System.out.println("The square root of the number " + num +" is equal to " +guess);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry the number that you entered is not a positive number, and it does not have a root of two");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use another `do-while` loop instead that wraps the `if-else`. Also, do not forget to keep reading the user input. No rocket science.

Comment: Does this code Iterate to the one before error is less than 1% ? or does it also iterate the one that its error is less than 1% ?  Thakns

Comment: My suggestion would be **not** to use float/double as controls. Find a way to do it using a boolean. Answer : if when the condition is checked `error` is greater than 0.01 it will run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new counter that only gets increased in the (former) exit loop condition.

```
int exit = 0;

do {
  ...
  if (error <= 0.01) {
    exit++;
  }
} while (exit < 2);
```

Comment: The condition would be `if (error <= 0.01)`, instead of `if (error > 0.01)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value only when the error is *strictly* less than 1%, you need to change the `while` condition.
Changing it to `error >= 0.01` says *"iterate, even when error is exactly equal to 1%, so we get a final error less than 1%"*.

Also, your `if (num <= 0)` allows a division by zero to happen, when `num` is exactly zero.
Let's check:

```
num = 0;
guess = num / 2;     // guess = 0
r = num / guess;     // r = 0 / 0
```

Looking at the below code should give you a clearer idea. I've commented it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the desired positive number in order to find its root of two: ");

    double num = kb.nextDouble();
    double guess=0;
    double r, g1, error;

    // Previous code allowed a division by zero to happen.
    // You may return immediately when it's zero.
    // Besides, you ask clearly for a *positive* number.
    // You should check firstly if the input is invalid.

    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry the number that you entered is not a positive number, and it does not have a root of two");
    }

    // Since you assigned guess to zero, which is the sqrt of zero,
    // you only have to guess when it's strictly positive.

    if (num > 0) {
        guess = num/2;

        // Notice the slight change in the while condition.

        do {
            r = num/guess;
            g1 = guess;
            guess = (guess+r)/2;
            error = (guess-g1)/guess;
            if (error < 0) {
                error = -error;
            }
        } while(error >= 0.01);
    }

    // Finally, print the result.
    System.out.println(
        "The square root of the number " + num +
        " is equal to " + guess
    );
}
```